# Am I understanding how Api sessions work correctly?

Tags: api, soap-api, c#

So I'm using the C# SOAP api w/ OAuth.

- User A logs in, does something that will take 60 seconds
- User B logs in 10 seconds into User A's process, and finishes in 5 seconds
- User A cannot make another request to the API once User B finished because User A's access token, session, and possibly server URL are no longer valid?

A way around this would be to store User A's Access Token and server URL, and depending on my settings for when a session expires(say, 12 hrs), I use the same server URL and Access Token as User A.

Also, both users are using the same login(a master API login).

Is this correct?

Comment: Are the users using the same application on the same computer?

Comment: It depends how you mean that. It will be the same application, both users could be on different computers. They are using the same login(a master API login).

Comment: OK, the user A and B threw me because I was thinking they were using different Salesforce credentials, so wasn't sure how the Session ID was causing problems. I think that an API user can have multiple Session IDs active at a time, but I haven't used OAuth. I've only used the SOAP login method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One username can be logged on from multiple places at the same time as each machine has a separate session. What you need to be wary of however, is that if User A and User B in this scenario are two people using one set of credentials, you'll need to make sure that you're not breaking the terms of your licence.

If the credentials are being used for an integration piece where there's no ownership of data per se then you might be ok, if you're somehow tagging information to make it specific to User A or User B then you should be using two licences (and hence two sets of credentials) instead.

Comment: Good point about the licensing. I'm trying to understand it more, so I looked at the [SF MSA](http://www2.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce_MSA.pdf).  I didn't see anything about API access in this manner.  What if you have a legacy application that has always allowed users to enter their contact information into the legacy system and now you've purchased SF and want their contact information pushed up to SF?  You need to buy licenses for each user? Do you know if there is some documentation that defines at what point a user license needs to be purchased in scenarios like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If they are using the same Salesforce username, they can both be logged in a the same time on different computers with different OAuth tokens, and each of them will have a separate session. Unless I misunderstand, this shouldn't cause a direct conflict.